# JavaScript Form Submit() Completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

Is there a way to call the javascript form submit() function or the JQuery $.submit() function  and make sure that it completes the submit process?  Specifically, within a form, I am trying to submit a form within an IFrame.  From the parent form, I am submitting the IFrame with the following code...

```
document.frames.IFRAME_Items.document.forms[0].submit();
```

The parent form then saves and closes.  However, currently the IFrame is not completing the post before the parent form saves and closes.  Is there any way using a JQuery callback or something in JavaScript to ensure this submit process completes before the parent form closes?

Comment: if your `<iframe>` is coming from an external website you wont be able to do anything. see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same%5Forigin%5Fpolicy

Comment: @adardesign This is obviously not the case however, as he is able to access the iframe's form from the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form onsubmit="return controlParentForm();" id="parentForm">
...
</form>
```

JS:

```
var controlSubmitParentForm = 0;
function controlParentForm(){

   var ret = false;

   if (controlSubmitParentForm==0){

     controlSubmitParentForm = 1;
     document.frames.IFRAME_Items.document.forms[0].submit();
     setTimeout(controlParentForm, 200);

   }
   else if (controlSubmitParentForm==1){

     if (document.frames.IFRAME_Items.document.readyState=="complete"){
        controlSubmitParentForm = 2;
        document.getElementById("parentForm").submit();
     }
     setTimeout(controlParentForm, 200);

   }
   else if (controlSubmitParentForm==2){
       // controls for "parentForm"
       ret = true;
       controlSubmitParentForm = 0;
   }

   return ret;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best what you can do is to submit the iframe's form asynchronously with help of [jQuery Form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/). This way you can wait until the response is returned. It also provides a `success` callback handler which you can use to submit the parent page's form.

Comment: This would be ideal, but I couldn't get either method to work (ajaxForm or ajaxSubmit) with the iFrame.